# updating tables for left outer joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know a good reference for updating tables for left outer joins?

Do I create the column I wish to store before executing the left outer join then populate the column?

I wish to store segmentspatialdata in a new table or add a row to an existing table that would contain values from segmentspatialdata but I'm not sure where the insert statement would go if I were to do that.

```
SELECT 
    a.rowid,
    a.Season,
    a.Name,
    a.Latitude,
    a.Longitude,
    b.rowid,
    b.Season,
    b.Name,
    b.Latitude,
    b.Longitude,
    CAST('LINESTRING(' +  a.Longitude  +' '+ a.Latitude  +', '+ 
    b.Longitude  +' '+ b.Latitude  + ')' AS GEOGRAPHY) AS segmentspatialdata
FROM 
    hurracane a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    hurracane b

ON     
    b.rowid = a.rowid + 1 
    AND b.season = a.season
    AND b.name = a.name

WHERE 
    b.rowid IS NOT NULL   
ORDER BY a.rowid
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQcnh.jpg)

Comment: Why dont you use `UPDATE FROM`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "updating tables for left outer joins". Can you explain further. In your sample query, which column do you want to update?

Comment: this makes it into a regular join "where  b.rowid IS NOT NULL".

Comment: I have attached an image see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQcnh.jpg I wish to store segmentationspatialdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where b.rowid IS NOT NULL
makes it a regular join

```
insert into table (segmentspatialdata)   
SELECT CAST('LINESTRING(' +  a.Longitude  +' '+ a.Latitude  +', '+ 
b.Longitude  +' '+ b.Latitude  + ')' AS GEOGRAPHY) AS segmentspatialdata
FROM 
    hurracane a
join 
    hurracane b
     ON b.rowid = a.rowid + 1 
    AND b.season = a.season
    AND b.name = a.name
```

Comment: Hey Pap, is this a new query or should my code be replaced with what you written? There is a missing parathensis . If I add columns as above then I get:The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
 How do I display code in the comments neatly?

Comment: @Nusc You question is not clear.  This would be the answer to "I wish to store segmentspatialdata in a new table"